# Why create_superuser manager is not working in custom user model?

Tags: django

When I try to create a superuser in my app I get the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\DirCom\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\DirCom\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 88, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 183, in handle
    validate_password(password2, self.UserModel(**fake_user_data))
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 561, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 338, in __set__
    super().__set__(instance, value)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\prod\DirCom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 235, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "User.persona" must be a "Persona" instance.
```

Before that `createsuperuser` step I have a custom script that creates the first Persona of the project, and what I'm trying is to assign the first person created with ID 1 to this superuser.

My model looks like this:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    """
        Clase para generar mi modelo de Persona que es el modelo
        previo a crear un usuario, en este modelo se guardan todos
        los datos personales
    """
    DEPENDENCIES_CHOICES = (
        ("1", "Rectorado - Gabinete"),
        ("2", "Vice Rectorado"),
        ("3", "Rectorado - Secretaria General"),
    )

    VINC_CHOICES = (("1", "Contratado"), ("2", "Permanente"),)

    gov_id = models.CharField("documento de identidad", max_length=50, unique=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(
        "foto de perfil", upload_to="profiles", blank=True, null=True
    ) 
    email = models.EmailField("correo electrónico", max_length=254, unique=True) 
    first_name = models.CharField("nombres", blank=True, null=True, max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField("apellidos", blank=True, null=True, max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField("ciudad", blank=True, null=True,  max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField("número de teléfono", blank=True, null=True, max_length=30)
    dependency = models.CharField("dependencia", blank=True, null=True, choices=DEPENDENCIES_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    vinc_type = models.CharField("tipo de vinculación", blank=True, null=True, choices=VINC_CHOICES, max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "persona"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ 
        Clase para generar mi modelo personalizado de usuarios
        AbstractBaseUser es un modelo de Django que ya trae integradas
        las funcionalidades de autenticación y manejo de sesiones
        Los campos que AbstractBaseUser ya trae predefinidos son:
        -id
        -password
        -is_superuser
    """
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (1, "Director"),
        (2, "Analista"),
        (3, "Cliente"),
        (4, "Técnico"),
    )

    username = models.CharField("nombre de usuario", max_length=50, unique=True)
    persona = models.OneToOneField(Persona, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("rol", choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=ROLE_CHOICES[2][0])
    is_staff = models.BooleanField("staff", default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField("activo", default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    # convierte el campo username en obligatorio por default
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"

    # para que la terminal nos pida estos datos al crear un superuser
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['persona']

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "usuario"
        ordering = ["-date_joined"]
```

And my `managers.py` file looks like

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager, models.Manager):
    """
        este método sobreescribe la manera en que nuestro modelo
        de usuarios crea los nuevos usuarios
        es un método privado de la clase BaseUserManager por eso
        el nombre empieza con _
    """

    def _create_user(
        self, username, persona, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields
    ):
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            persona_id=persona,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    """
        este es un método público que sirve para crear usuarios normales
        no administradores, desde el frente de la aplicación, este es el 
        método que usamos para crear los usuarios en el registro de la página web
    """

    def create_user(self, username, persona, password=None, **extra_fields):
        self._create_user(username, persona.id, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    """
        este es un método público que permite crear super usuarios, es decir,
        administradores con todos los permisos. Podemos crear usuarios desde
        la línea de comandos ejecutando python manage.py createsuperuser
    """

    def create_superuser(self, username, persona, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(
            username, persona, password, True, True, **extra_fields
        )
```

I already try to use

```
def create_superuser(self, username, persona, password=None, **extra_fields:
        p = Persona.objects.get(pk=persona)
        return self._create_user(
            username, p, password, True, True, **extra_fields
        )
```

But that does not work too
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The create-superuser script will always return an Object of User Type , when you assign a superuser to a type of any Model in your project you will get a mismatch error where User is not the same type as your model object

instead of having a Persona model along with User Model you can consider the User as Persona and customize the create user model with all the attribute of Persona as well as controlling is_superuser flag .

the major difference in super user case is the is_superuser flag set to true
What you need to do is to create a method that creates a Persona-Like User Object and assign a is_superuser flag to that object

[Follow the link here to help you create your own create user command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Comment: Thanks
I was supossed to do in that way but my college teacher ask me to separate users and persons in two different models

Comment: Then if that's the case,  I think you have to build a one-to-one relation between a user and a persona ,that is each persona is a user and use post_save() signal in Persona Model  to create a  user opposite to the created persona , passing all persona attributes along with is_superuser flag to it